# How can i make a pop up activity when i got a notification?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I m a student, I'm working on a project but i m  stuck. I didn't find what i want , so I ask here. I m learning english, sorry for mistakes.
I want to find a way, when i got a notification(even if I don't use the phone), it show a pop up  activity(screen).
How can I make a pop up activity when I got a notification?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receivers are used if you want to notify your app about an event occurred. i think it may help in your case.